# Adding content of Array into where Condition in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make this function get() that takes tbl_name and condition which will be used in WHERE.

Here $condition is an array like:

```
$condition = array(
        'id' => 'some id',
        'anycondition' => 'any value');

public function get($tbl_name, $condition = null) {
    if($condition) {
        $data = "select * from '$tbl_name' WHERE '$condition'";
    }
    else {
        $data = $tbl_name;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I want the echo be like this

```
select * from $tbl_name WHERE id='some id' and anycondition='any value'
```

Comment: And is there anything you have tried?

Comment: From where does this array originate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM '$tbl_name' WHERE id='".$condition['id']."' AND anycondition='".$condition['anycondition']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data="select * from '$tbl_name' WHERE 
(select array_to_string($condition, 'and', '') as condition);
```

here (in array_to_string) :

```
first parameter -->array

 2nd -->concatenation text

3rd -->replacement of the null value in your array
```

Comment: if the no. of condition in the array is not fixed one..you can convert the array values as string as described above. and then use that in the query

Answer (score 0):

This a horrible way a approach a class, which handles the database layer of your application. If I was you I read throughly into mysqli driver https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and come up with a better solution.

But here is what I think you were trying to accomplish in your opening post.

```
class A
{
    public function sqlSelect($dbh, $tableName, $params=array()) {
        if (!empty($param)) {
            foreach ($params as $field => $value) {
                // http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
                $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $dbh);
                $whereSql[] = sprintf("%s = %s", $field, $value); 
            }
            $whereSql = implode(" AND ", $whereSql);
            return sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s", 
                           $tableName, $whereSql);
        }
        return sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s", $tableName);
    }
}

$condition = array(
    'id' => 1234,
    'some_other_column' => 'someOtherValue'
);
echo A.sqlSelect('SomeTableName', $condition);
echo A.sqlSelect('SomeOtherTableName');

Output:
SELECT * FROM SomeTableName WHERE id = 1234 AND some_other_column = 'someOtherValue'
SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTableName
```